# Handle different Web API requests using a single application

Tags: android, mobile

i'm looking for a solution.I have 10 websites and a single android application. This apk is placed on every site. Is there any solution to check this out that from which website this apk is downloaded so that we can handle api requests as according to the websites? The working of every website is same. I want to handle the api request using their different URLs. any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can put a static string variable and generate 10 apk of this app , and always send it with your http request
- give the user a choice , to select from where he/she downloads the apk , after that save it into your local database , and send it with your http request